# Unknown tag name "form_rest"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm having trouble making a form to work using Twig and Sf2.

```
Unknown tag name "form_rest" in MyBundle:Default:home.html.twig at line 40
```

In the view it reads:

```
{% form_rest(form) %}
```

I can try any `form*` methods. Same result.
The controler has something like this:

```
public function userEmailAddressFormAction()
{
  $userEmailAddress = new UserEmailAddress();
  $form = $this->createForm(new UserEmailAddressType(), $userEmailAddress);

  return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:userEmailAddress.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

Why isn't Twig loading the helper?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a tag; it's a function. So, use `{{` and `}}` instead of `{%` and `%}`:

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

Comment: @samura not ur fault... such a bad documentation